# How to fix date field filter in the angular-kendo grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have data in JSON format, with all fields as strings. When I display it in the grid (I use kendo grid), it treat it as string, even if I create custom date field. So if I filter by existing date, then it do not match.

Note: I tried to convert source of data from string to date, it didn't fix filtering problem.

Please see images and code below, and git hub example.
https://github.com/sam-klok/kendo-angular-app/tree/master/src/app/grid-second

```
export const customers = [{
    'ContactName': 'Maria Anders',
    'DOB': '01/31/2000'
}, {
    'ContactName': 'Ana Bokov',
    'DOB': '11/23/1974'
}, {
    'ContactName': 'Antonio Moreno',
},

export class GridSecondComponent implements OnInit {
  public gridData: any[] = customers;


<kendo-grid
    [resizable]="true"
    [kendoGridBinding]="gridData"
    [filterable]="true"
    [groupable]="true"
    [sortable]="true"
    [pageSize]="7"
    [pageable]="true"
    [height]="510">
    <kendo-grid-column field="ContactName" title="Contact" [width]="120"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="DOB" 
    title="Date Of Birth" [width]="200" 
        format="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}">
        <ng-template kendoGridFilterCellTemplate let-filter let-column="column">
            <kendo-grid-date-filter-cell 
                [column]="column" 
                [filter]="filter">
            </kendo-grid-date-filter-cell>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>    
</kendo-grid>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per kendo-angular forum issue been in the using string instead of Date. I put a note, that I did conversion, but in my code, conversion was incorrect. When I corrected it, filter started to work. Array conversion below.

```
interface ICustomer{
    ContactName: string;
    DOB?: Date;
}

export const customerObjs = customers.map(
    x=>({
        ContactName: x.ContactName,
        DOB: x.DOB ? new Date(x.DOB) : undefined
    })
)
```

[image]

Some related docs are here:
https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-date-filter-not-working
[How to convert TypeScript array to generic array of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75346419/how-to-convert-typescript-array-to-generic-array-of-class)

Answer (score 0):

From kendo-angular support email: In order to format, filter, sort on do any other data modifications, the dates need to be valid JavaScript Date objects, instead string representations:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/knowledge-base/grid-handling-of-dates-data-operations/

In short, the DOB field value must be changed like:

```
export const customers = [{
    'Id': 'ALFKI',
    ....
    'Fax': '030-0076545',
    'DOB': new Date('01/01/2000')
},
```

Please check the following demo for more details:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/basics/#toc-date-filter