# How to convert TypeScript array to generic array of class

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, class

I have JSON source array with all values as strings. I'm trying to convert it to another array of typed objects. I'm getting errors. How to properly write this code? Thank you.

Error 1:
Conversion of type '({ Id: string; CompanyName: string; ...)[]' to type 'Dest' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

Erorr 2:
../grid-second.component.ts:12:10 - error TS2740: Type 'Dest' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
12   public gridData: any[] = destination;

```
export const source = [{
    'Id': 'ALFKI',
    'CompanyName': 'Alfreds Futterkiste',
    'DOB': '01/31/2000' // may not exists
}, {
    'Id': 'ANATR',
    'CompanyName': 'Ana Bokov Emparedados y helados',
}, 

export class Dest{
    public Id: string = "";
    public CompanyName: string = "";
    public DOB?: Date
}

export const destination = <Dest>source;  // Error 1.
```

In the Angular component:

```
public gridData: any[] = destination;  // Error 2.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a constructor to your class and create an instances of it using map:

```ts
class Dest {
    public Id: string = "";
    public CompanyName: string = "";
    public DOB?: Date;

    constructor(id: string, companyName: string, dob: string | undefined) {
        this.Id = id;
        this.CompanyName = companyName;

        // TODO: not seeing Timezone in source objects.
        this.DOB = dob ? new Date(dob): undefined;
    }
}

const destination: Dest[] = source.map(x => new Dest(x.Id, x.CompanyName, x.DOB));
```

If you dont really need a class and you dont want to play with `new` - you can utilize Interfaces or Types. But anyway, you will need to convert string DOB to Date DOB:

```ts
interface IDest {
    Id: string;
    CompanyName: string;
    DOB?: Date;
}

const destination: IDest[] = source.map(x => ({...x, DOB: x.DOB ? new Date(x.DOB) : undefined}));
```

Playground: [click](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#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)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `Object.assign()` for this purpose. Usually I'm doing this in a [RXJS Map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) as part of getting data back from a server.

However, you can also use the [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
newSource = source.map(element => Object.assign(new Dest(),  element));
```

Although, given your code, with a hard coded array I'd probably just create the values directly as part of the array creation, as opposed to processing it later:

```
export const source = [Object.assign(new Dest, {
    'Id': 'ALFKI',
    'CompanyName': 'Alfreds Futterkiste',
    'DOB': '01/31/2000' // may not exists
}), Object.assign(new Dest, {
    'Id': 'ANATR',
    'CompanyName': 'Ana Bokov Emparedados y helados',
})
]
```

Comment: `public DOB?: Date` in class, not a string, I guess using Object.assign in this case will be a bit buggy

Comment: @SergeySosunov Great call out; that string value should be converted to a date object somehow.  IT could be done as part of either approach above.

Comment: I tried this .assign approach, and in Developer Mode in browser I still see strings, not dates. Strange..

Comment: @samsergiyklok Did you use Sergey's suggestion of converting the dates, which is not present in the code samples for this answer?

Comment: @JeffryHouser I use approach in previous answer successfully, thank you.